# Creating threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a newbie to Java and wondering whether I can create threads in following way.

Desired Java Code :

```
Class MyClass {

    Myclass(){
        Statement1;//Create a thread1 to call a function
        Statement2;//Create a thread2 to call a function
        Statement3;//Create a thread3 to call a function
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create threads like the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing GregInYEG, you should check out the tutorial, but the simple explanation is as follows:

You need to create an object class which either extends Thread or implements Runnable. In this class, create (actually, overload) a void method called "run." Inside this method is where you put the code that you would like this thread to execute once it is forked. It could simply be a call to another function if you wish. Then, when you would like to spawn a thread of this type, create one of these objects and call the "start" (not run!) method of this object. eg newThread.start();

It's important to call "start" and not "run" because a run call will simply call the method just like any other, without forking a new thread.

Still, be sure to read up in further detail and there are many more important aspects of concurrency, especially that of locking shared resources.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) includes a page on [defining and starting threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). You might want to read through it along with the other pages in the concurrency tutorial.

Comment: In particular, the section "High Level Concurrency Objects" may be valuable. Frequently the higher-level objects are simpler to use.

Comment: can't quite understand from any of them. Created an empty runnable class and trying to call 2 different functions from different classes. Eclipse doesn't even allow me to write the class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You want to put your logic for each statement inside a [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) implementation, and then pass each constructed `Runnable` to a new instance of [`Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). Check out those 2 classes and it should become fairly obvious what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all written here. The thread can be created in a two ways.

1. To extend thread class . [YouTube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/hsKYDpP9xRs)
2. To implement Runnable Interface  [YouTube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/X-RmOxNiHFs)

Example for the first method

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {


public void run()
{
    int iterations = 4;


        for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++)
        {

            System.out.println("Created Thread is running " + Thread.currentThread().getId()  + " Printing "  + i) ;
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }


    System.out.println("End of program"); 
}
```

}

To create a thread

```
MyThread myThread = new MyThread();

myThread.start();
```

Second method to implement runnable interface

```
public class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    int iterations = 4;


    for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Runnable Thread is running " + Thread.currentThread().getId()  + " Printing "  + i) ;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }


System.out.println("End of program"); 
}
```

}

To create a thread

```
new Thread(new RunnableThread()).start();
```

So I think you can use both of these methods in you case statements